# Cannot complete transaction using PayPal Javascript Standard Integration Example

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, paypal, e-commerce

I am following this example for PayPal

https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration

I created a paypal business account and copied the Client ID and Secret into .env file and into index.html file to replace `test` in string, and changed the $100 value to $1 value in paypal-api.js

When I load it with `npm install` and `npm start` from VS Code, I get the paypal page

[image]

When I try to enter the SandBox credentials it gives me an error `you are trying to log in with seller credentials`. I don't understand what I am supposed to use these for if I can't log in with them

Next, when I try to enter the CC details without logging in, it says transaction completed. But I do not see any funds in my paypal account not any funds taken from my CC

What am I doing wrong? Why is this integration not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I do not see any funds in my paypal account

Which PayPal account? The sandbox one that the client-id corresponds to?

See your list of Sandbox accounts at https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts . Create more as desired. The payer cannot be the same as the receiver of a transaction, which is why you received an error message.

---

All of the above applies to the sandbox environment, [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) . Nothing you do in sandbox mode will reflect in the live environment, the two are completely separated.

Comment: I have 2 sandbox accounts, business and personal. I tried to log into them with the provided passwords, but it says `Some of your info isn't correct. Please try again.`

Comment: I don't understand what this sandbox accounts are for, are they for sending or receiving money? How can I send money from a real bank to a sandbox account? How can I send from a sandbox account to a real account? What happens to the money? It doesn't make any sense, it's easier for me to send $1 from a real bank to a real account to verify it works

Comment: Both. You can't. You can't. It's unlimited and make-believe, for creating test transactions. Testing in live is not with small amounts is not practical for development purposes, and can often be declined in general for fraud prevention reasons (paying your own accounts is not permitted, per credit card company rules)